# Cloud Composer Instance Nodes and Autoscaling

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a few DAGs that only run for a few hours a day, after which the Cloud Composer cluster does nothing. I'm trying to understand the worker pool auto-scaling mechanism:

- If I set the cluster size to 3 nodes, but autoscale with min=1, max=10, then set a DAG's `concurrency=10`, will Composer run on those 3 nodes until the DAG hints at it that it needs for resources, at which point it auto scales to 10 nodes? Then will it destroy those additional 7 nodes when the DAG is done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have decided to elaborate little bit more to @SNeumann answer. As for now, Composer doesn't support Kubernetes clusters with autoscaling enabled. This is due to there's a complex conversation around Kuberenetes resource requests and how those can't be estimated for Airflow pods at this time.

Feature requests have already been filed: [1](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116455284), [2](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117119946) to support worker autoscaling based on DAG demand. I suggest [subscribing it](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue) to keep updated as you'll receive e-mails regarding its progress.

According to the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-kubernetes-pod-operator#environment-resources):

> the Airflow scheduler and workers are in the same GKE cluster, the
>   schedulers and workers won't work properly if the competition results
>   in resource starvation.

For now, you need to enable autoscaling on node level and write .yaml, then update `minReplicas: 1` and `maxReplicas: 50` like in the Medium tutorial posted by @SNeumann.

I hope you find the above pieces of information useful.

Answer (score 4):

Cloud Composer doesn't natively support auto-scaling, but you can hack it by changing airflow config and change the underlying k8s settings.

There's a great article on how to do it here: https://medium.com/traveloka-engineering/enabling-autoscaling-in-google-cloud-composer-ac84d3ddd60

Answer (score 0):

[Environment scaling](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/environment-scaling) is now natively supported in Cloud Composer 2:

> Cloud Composer 2 brings environments that scale automatically based on the demands of your workflows. For more information about Cloud Composer 2, see [Major versions of Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/composer-versioning-overview), [Environment scaling](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/environment-scaling), and [Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/composer/pricing) pages in the documentation.

Example using `gcloud` command:

```shell
gcloud beta composer composer environments update <ENVIRONMENT_NAME> \
--location <LOCATION> \
--min-workers <WORKERS_MIN> \
--max-workers <WORKERS_MAX>
```

Comment: Yes, but does it work?  :)